# Clean a CSV file with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a  comma separated values (CSV) file, that I need to reduce to one column. Let me show you some example:

[image: Example]

I need to extract this in every line or just leave IP:port like this:

[image: Example2]

It doesn't matter if I have to do it in several steps.

I've tried deleting X amount of characters at the beginning of every line but the issue is that not every line is the same length at the beginning of after the IP address!

Comment: Please provide text, not images.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio The link you gave me works partially fine, but all the examples they have there are just IP withoout port, and I need ip:port, thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1778627 With the explanation given on the link, you should be able to add the port numbers. The accepted answer's find what is `^.+?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+).+` adding the port number gives this `^.+?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+\:\d+).+$`